# Make a function redirect to other functions depending on a variable

Tags: python, variables, terminal

I am currently making a game in Python. It's command only.

Let's say there is a loced door in the game, and you need the key to open the door. I can all the basic about variables, but apparently not this.

My code looks like this:

```
def room_1():
    door = 0
    print
    choice = raw_input('>: ')

    if choice.lower() == 'open door':
        if door == '0':
            print
            print 'Sorry, you need a key to open this door.'
            room_1()
        if door == '1':
            room_2()
```

I am not quite sure why this is not working.

Could someone here please help me out? Thank you very much!

Comment: Explain _"not working"_

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Thats because you initially declared the variable `door` as an `int`, but you are comparing it to a `string` `'0'` (and `'1'`).

It should be,

```
if door == 0:
   .....
```

and

```
if door == 1:
   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt open your string in the raw_input function call:

```
def room_1():
    door = 0
    print
    choice = raw_input('>: ')

    if choice.lower() == 'open door':
        if door == '0':
            print
            print 'Sorry, you need a key to open this door.'
            def room_1()
        if door == '1':
            room_2()
```

Comment: Also, the OP most probably wants to remove the `def` too, keeping just `room_1()`.

Comment: I just wrote a new code really fast here at stackoverflow to show everyone. Everything is ok in the actual code :)

Comment: @StigHetl Don't do that :p And if you do, check for such errors at least :p

Comment: @Keyser I will! Hehe :P